# Java File Monitor

Tags: java, watchservice, file-monitoring

I currently have a java program that monitors a remote folder over a network. If files are added or deleted, the log is populated with this information.

If the connection to the folder drops, and reconnects, the monitor will resume as usual.

However, a bug that I am incurring is that if the connection drops, a file is added to the folder, and the connection is reestablished, the monitor does not populate the log to reflect that this file has been added. If it is deleted then the log is still updated accordingly.

I am using a WatchService and WatchKey to monitor the folder, and I believe this is where the error is occurring. The Key value remains null when reconnecting, even if a file is added. Is there anyway to assign a value other than null when reconnecting to ensure that any new files are discovered?

```
    WatchService service = fs.newWatchService();
    //Need an assignment other than service.poll()
    WatchKey key = service.poll(POLLING_INTERVAL , TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    populateLog("KEY: "+key);//Debuging
    // Dequeuing events
    if(key!=null){ Populate logs...
```

Comment: No help without code

Comment: This is most likely normal behavior for whatever platform you are running on. Take a look at the javadoc, there is some mention about platform dependency and possible behavior.

Comment: You will probably have to save the state of the folder before the connection drops and compare it to the state of the folder after you reconnect.